# Check filename contains a string in bash script

Tags: bash, sh

I had written a script for moving/Copying files to particular folder.
I need to check the filenames and move to respective folders.
I can read the filenamess but, checking the filename contains a string giving the error.

Here my script ::

```
for eachfile in *; do
  echo "INSIDE"
  echo $eachfile
  if [ [ $eachfile =  "CHPOE05"* ] ]; then
    echo  $eachfile
  else
    echo "invalid"
  fi
done
```

Below is my error:

```
Uploading file IN PCS FOLDER
INSIDE
CHPOE0500001.txt
INCOK1IGT1.sh: line 44: [: too many arguments
invalid
INSIDE
CHPOE050i1001.txt
INCOK1IGT1.sh: line 44: [: too many arguments
```

Comment: Whenever you have a shell script error, a good first step is to cut and paste your code into [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and correct the errors (important) and warnings (might be important) that it identifies. If you have trouble understanding its messages, then come here and ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the spaces between `[ [` and `] ]` seems to work for me.

Comment: Thanks.. It works for me also.
I had a one more doubt. How i will be adding or condition.
Like,
 if [ [ $eachfile =  "CHPOE05"* ] || [ $eachfile =  "CHPOE05"* ] ]
this way it will work??

Comment: If you have a new (unrelated) question, it is better to ask a new question here. Aside from this, I don't quite understand your question here.